# Beamer: how to hide TOC from first overlay slide

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, overlays

**I'd like to have the TOC appear line-by-line, starting with an empty slide with just the `frametitle` visible** (to be more precise, I want it to be completely grayed out according to `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`). This is my best attempt so far:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \onslide<2->{\tableofcontents[pausesubsections,pausesections]}
\end{frame}
```

However, this

- leaves only the first section grayed-out and hides the rest completely on the first slide
- one the second slide, it shows the first section and the first subsection simultaneously

Without `\onslide`, the first frame starts with the first section already visible.

I've also tried

- inserting `\stepcounter{beamerpauses}` before `\tableofcontents`,
- `\pause`, and
- `\begin{frame}[<+(1)->]`,

without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-using a little trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318257/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\trickbeamer}{%
        \advance\beamer@slideinframe by-1%
        }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Toc}

        \pause
        \trickbeamer

    \tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}


\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\section{section name}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zubo You're welcome!